# How can i register a DbContext with MySQL in .NET 7

Tags: c#, mysql, dbcontext, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I want to migrate my project to .NET 7 and I don't know how to connect to my MySQL Database. Before my project was on .NET 6 and I used Pomelo to connect to my database. Is there currently a Nuget Package for .NET 7 to connect to MySQL?

#### How i registered my DbContext before with Pomelo

```
services.AddDbContextPool<MyContext>(options => options
    .UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext")));
```

Comment: Pomelo works already. Why the question? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when I use Pomelo Im not able to read from the database. For example _context.People.ToList() throws an exception.

MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'.

Comment: Everything works now. I installed the alpha version of Pomelo. Thank you very much.

Comment: [Pomelo 6.02 explicitly requires EF Core 6.x](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/6.0.2). How did you install the package in the first place? You should have gotten a NuGet error or warning. Pomelo works fine for the last 6 years. If you tried to install Pomelo 6.x on a project with EF Core 7, NuGet would raise a downgrade error. Did you add EF Core 7 after installing Pomelo?

Comment: First I couldn't install it, because it said i need to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational at first, so I did that and I could install Pomelo on .NET 7. I just had a warning but i could still run the application just when i opened a View that needed data from the db i got an error message.

Comment: So you did get an error telling you the versions were incompatible. Such errors shouldn't be ignored. You can use Pomelo and EF Core *6* on .NET 7. In fact, Pomelo would have installed 6.0.7 automatically, since it's a NuGet dependency

Comment: Thank you but as i mentioned i use the alpha Version of Pomelo now that supports EF Core 7. I hope there will be an official release soon.